# OpenTK C# GL.Color3 не меняет цвет

Tags: c#, opentk

Пытаюсь поменять цвет отображения точек в элементе управления glControl с помощью GL.Color3, но цвет не меняется. Подскажите, что не так, пожалуйста. Отрисовка происходит одним непонятным цветом, который я не задавал.
Код ниже:

```
private void glControl1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isLoaded)
        {
            GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
            GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
            GL.ClearColor(Color.Black);
            GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
            GL.LoadMatrix(ref _modelview);
            DrawAxes();
            DrawPointCloud();
            glControl1.SwapBuffers();

        }
    }
public void DrawAxes()
    {
        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Lines);
        GL.Color3(Color.Red);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(400, 0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 400, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 400);
        GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
        GL.End();
    }

    public void DrawPointCloud()
    {
        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Points);

        for (int i = 0; i < vertexes.Count; i++)
        {
            GL.Color3(Color.Yellow);
            GL.Vertex3(vertexes[i].X, vertexes[i].Y, vertexes[i].Z);
        }
        GL.End();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо было добавить строчку GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting); в событие glControl1_Paint и все заработало. Я новичок в OpenTK, поэтому объяснения четкого дать более по этому поводу не могу. Надеюсь кому-то это может быть поможет :)